# Passing arguments to groovy closure

Tags: groovy, closures

Wrote the below code which is working fine:

```
def teams = ['x', 'y', 'z']
def list = [ [id:1, team1: 'x', team2:'y' ], [id:2, team1: 'z', team2:'y' ]]
def function = { 
    teams.inject( [:]) { result, team ->  
            result[team] = list.findAll { 
                team in [it.team1, it.team2] 
            }.size()
            result 
    }
}
println function()
```

Results the following output:

```
[x:1, y:2, z:1]
```

Now, trying to passing condition as closure to the `function` as below:

```
def function = { closure -> 
    teams.inject( [:]) { result, team ->
        result[team] = list.findAll(closure).size()
        result
    }
}

def t = { team in [it.team1, it.team2] }

println function(t)
```

But it says below error. `team` is available in the context though.

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: team for class: testclosure
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: team for class: testclosure
>       at testclosure$_run_closure3.doCall(testclosure.groovy:8)
>       at testclosure$_run_closure2$_closure6.doCall(testclosure.groovy:6)
>       at testclosure$_run_closure2.doCall(testclosure.groovy:6)
>       at testclosure.run(testclosure.groovy:12)

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the straight way to pass all required params to closure:

```
def teams = ['x', 'y', 'z']
def list = [ [id:1, team1: 'x', team2:'y' ], [id:2, team1: 'z', team2:'y' ]]

def function = { closure -> teams.inject( [:]) { result, team ->  
    result[team] = list.findAll{closure(team,it)}.size() 
    result 
} }

def t = {x1,x2-> x1 in [x2.team1, x2.team2]}

println function(t)
```

or you could use `rehydrate`, but you can't access closure parameters:

```
def f = {_x,_y, closure->
    def x = _x
    def y = _y
    closure.rehydrate(this,this,this).call()
}


println f(111,222, {x+y})   //this works
println f(111,222, {_x+_y}) //this fails
```

Comment: Thank you daggett. I was totally ignore `findAll{..}`, was trying `findAll(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Mean while I proceeded with another `groovy recipe` called `curry` on the `closure` as shown below:

```groovy
def teams = ['x', 'y', 'z']
def list = [ [id:1, team1: 'x', team2:'y' ], [id:2, team1: 'z', team2:'y' ]]
def function = { closure -> teams.inject( [:]) { result, team ->  result[team] = list.findAll(closure.curry(team)).size() ; result } }
def t = { param1, it  -> param1 in [it.team1, it.team2] }

println function(t)
```